# Is it possible to write these commands in Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible

Just want to know that can we achieve all our linux commands using Ansible Playbook. For eg. Is it possible to write playbook for below commands.

1. sudo nginx --version
2. service httpd status
3. sudo yum update

Answer (score 1):

> sudo nginx --version

```yaml
---
- hosts: a_host
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: get all installed packages
      package_facts:
        manager: auto

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"
```

> service httpd status

Ansible should be used a declerative language. Meaning you [should provide the desired state in a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html). However, sometimes it's necessary to [ask the status](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html).

```yaml
---
- hosts: a_host
  tasks:
    - name: Populate service facts
      service_facts:

    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services
```

> sudo yum update

Please [read the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html).

```yaml
---
- hosts: a_host
  tasks:
    - name: upgrade all packages
      yum:
        name: '*'
        state: latest
```

Comment: For the status, there is the [`service_facts`module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html) that could do the job